# Why do we need to sign the android application after decompiling and rebuilding it?

Tags: android

After decompiling an android app and then rebuilding it, we have to sign the APK, why? What happens if its not signed?

Answer (score 0):

Primarily the purpose of signing the application is to identify the author of the app. The app developer holds the key to the certification.

Since the key is private to the developer, is encrypted, unique, and probably un-hackable, it proves that the application is developed by you( or the person who signed the application. Hence it proves the authenticity of the application.

> Android requires that all apps be digitally signed with a certificate before they can be installed. Android uses this certificate to identify the author of an app, and the certificate does not need to be signed by a certificate authority. Android apps often use self-signed certificates. The app developer holds the certificate's private key

[Official Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

**Edit**

Signing in general ensures that any modifications to the artefact are detectable (as the signature will no longer be valid), and the verification performed on device in particular ensure both that all APKs are signed and that upgrades to installed APKs are signed by the same key. Thus, if the APK is modified it requires a new signature to be considered valid

Thanks [msbit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7003720/msbit)!

Comment: Signing in general ensures that any modifications to the artefact are detectable (as the signature will no longer be valid), and the verification performed on device in particular ensure both that all APKs are signed and that upgrades to installed APKs are signed by the same key. Thus, if the APK is modified it requires a new signature to be considered valid.